# Safe to parse user submitted code using Ripper?

Tags: ruby, ruby-ripper

I'm using the [Ruby 1.9 Ripper library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Ripper.html) to analyze specific parts of a source code by building it's sexp tree. From what I know, Ripper just uses a lexer / parser to do this.

Is it safe to run Ripper on a user submitted code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it does not actually evaluate any code, yes it is safe.

If you are talking about taking those s-expressions and evaluating them, then most certainly the answer seems to be: Not without cleaning it first. That cleaning process could be especially tricky though.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure, thanks! And no, I'm not evaluating them in any way.